# Алгоритм нанесения водяного знака

Tags: python, алгоритм, watermark

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существует ли какой то алгоритм нанесения водяного знака на фотографию? В универе дали тему курсовой нанести водяной знак на фото. Нужно именно нанести картинку на другую картинку без использования сторонних библиотек, работая только с пикселями(байтами) Желательно Python. Гуглить пытался, но выдаёт везде уже готовые решения с использованием библиотек

Comment: Чуть дольше погуглил и нашёл https://habr.com/ru/post/98743/. Не тестировал, но по описанию звучит похоже. В конце концов, можно взять код на знакомом вам языке и переписать его на ваш. Нашёл готовый алгоритм на c# https://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread2201596.html

Comment: Спасибо большое 

Comment: @Frehzy По ссылкам там используется библиотека PIL( сейчас Pillow). Если вам разрешат использовать хотя бы стандартные библитотеки, то в tkinter есть canvas, а в нем есть прозрачнось. Так что задача решилась бы быстро.

Comment: Вот нашел один из алгоритмов <https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2020/1806024/>, выдал гугл по поиску watermark photo "algorithm".